# what to log and what to ignore in Global.asax Application_Error()?

Tags: asp.net, .net, error-handling

Currently I have the following code snippet to handle errors in Global.asax Application_Error():

```
    var ex = server.GetLastError();
    server.ClearError();
    if (ex is HttpUnhandledException && ex.InnerException != null)
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
    // send some output to the user that they should contact support etc
```

It catches all errors, including 404 errors for example (when the user types a nonexistent .aspx URL, or when the browser asks for stuff like favicon.ico and static file requests are set up to go through the pipeline). There are two problems with this: this should not be logged (the log is full of useless 404 errors) and the original HTTP code should be sent back (otherwise search bots may index error pages etc.).

How would you decide what to log and what to ignore here? Basically I want to include application/business errors, which indicate bugs, and ignore "normal" HTTP errors. I also don't just want to exclude 404 errors only, there is also 403 and who knows what else.

Comment: Log everything - space is cheap and your time wasted trying to figure out what went wrong on production is not.

Comment: @JakubKonecki log everything - and your time will be wasted scrolling through non-actionable stuff.

Comment: @usr - we're talking about unhandled exceptions in `Application_Error`. If you have non-actionable stuff there you have some serious issues somewhere else... ;-)

Comment: @JakubKonecki every website has useless errors. Bots are doing all kinds of funky, non-dangerous stuff like messing with ViewState. Also, clients sometimes disconnect and so on. *All kinds* of useless stuff. See my answer for more examples.

Comment: Always log everything, who knows what will be useful ? I think you should use enterprise library for logging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: Enterprise library is a good way to log stuff, but I don't think it knows what to and what not to log.

Comment: Sadly, ASP.NET throws an incredible amount of exceptions while it's working normally, and some of that stuff makes it to Application_Error. Bots are a really good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple idea. The key to the solution is the fact that all business and other kinds of unexpected exceptions have an HTTP code of 500, while the normal HTTP exceptions don't, they have codes like 403, 404, etc. Here's a code snippet:

```
var ex = server.GetLastError();
if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() != 500)
    return; // the usual yellow error screen appears with the normal HTTP error code

// we handle the error ourselves
server.ClearError();
if (ex is HttpUnhandledException && ex.InnerException != null)
    ex = ex.InnerException;
// log the error, tell the user to contact support
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good: you log unhandled errors. The point of that is to weed out bugs. Humans cannot avoid bugs but we can quickly fix them.

Start with logging all errors. Then **blacklist individual errors** or categories of errors that you learn are useless. Within a few iterations you'll have a fairly clean log.

**Remove everything that is not actionable.** For example, your website will have bots performing crazy requests and so on. No action necessary, so you can remove them from the log.

I recommend that you also log seemingly useless errors into a supplementary log file so that you can scroll through it from time to time to make sure that everything is alright.

You especially want to know the **frequency of normally harmless errors**. Three deadlocks per day might be cool with you, but 300 might be too much.

I'll contribute a sketch of what your global error handler might contain:

```
static bool IsExceptionIgnored(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");

    var nestedExceptions = exception.GetExceptionChain();
    return nestedExceptions.Any(ex =>
        ex is ViewStateException ||
        ex.Message.Contains("Timeout") ||
        ex.Message.StartsWith("Invalid viewstate") ||
        ex.Message.Contains("potentially dangerous") ||
        ex.Message.Contains("The remote host closed the connection") ||
        ex.Message.Contains("System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate") ||
        ex.Message.Contains("System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError") ||
        ex.Message.Contains("0x80070032") ||
        (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404) ||
        ex is ThreadAbortException);
}
public static IEnumerable<Exception> GetExceptionChain(this Exception exception)
{
    if (exception == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");

    for (var current = exception; current != null; current = current.InnerException)
        yield return current;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's actually better than mine because it drills into AggregateException. You need to rewrite it so that it returns the exception, not the message. Callers can pick out the message if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebException ex = new WebException();
            HttpWebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            { 

            }
```

[image]

Comment: The question is about Global.asax Application_Error() event. Are you sure you must do a catch in the event's code?

Comment: @jlvaquero Yup i knew the event and i was also checking whether we can check exception type in this event or not, Well i am updating my code haven't tested yet but please do let me know if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Sorry but this is not relevant to ASP.NET (System.Net.HttpWebResponse vs System.Web.HttpResponse) and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @fejesjoco `this is not relevant to ASP.NET`(System.Net.HttpWebResponse vs System.Web.HttpResponse), Care to explain ?